# How to take back placed crafts?

Tags: medieval-engineers

After placing a Bed, or a Crafting Table, or a Small Chest on the ground, how to take it back, in order to re-place it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep <kbd>F</kbd> pressed for a few seconds while aiming at the placed craft and it will go to your inventory. There will even be a timer there so you know how much time remains to get it.